# Loop to remove only the ith character of the string

Tags: python

I have a loop function called `remove`and wish to show every loop result of removing only the ith character of the string.
Let say I have a string `"hello"`, and the expected output of the loop function is shown below:

```
remove("hello")
Remove the position 1: ello
Remove the position 2: hllo
Remove the position 3: helo
Remove the position 4: helo
Remove the position 5: hell
```

My codes for the function:

```
def remove(string):
    i=0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        removed=string.replace(string[i],"")
        print("Remove the position",i+1,":",removed)
        i=i+1
    return None
```

And the output of my code:

```
remove_one("hello")
Remove the position 1 : ello
Remove the position 2 : hllo
Remove the position 3 : heo
Remove the position 4 : heo
Remove the position 5 : hell
```

Seems that my codes not only remove the letter of the ith position, they also remove the letters when they are the same as the letter of the ith position.
How can I fix the codes that only remove the letter of the ith position?

Comment: The `replace` function removes all of them. You could just do something like: `removed = string[:i] + string[i+1:]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `replace` removes all the occurrences of the letter. What you want is simply:

```py
string = string[:i] + string[i+1:]
```

You can also use `del`:

```py
del string[i]
```

With the first solution, your code becomes:

```py
def remove(string):
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        removed = string[:i] + string[i+1:]
        print("Remove the position", i+1, ":", removed)
        i = i + 1
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points about the code...
`range` returns the values from 0 to the length of the string, so there is no need to set `i` equal to zero. In addition, the for loop cycles through the range values for you, so you don't need to set `i` (using `i = i +1`) at the bottom of the for loop.

```
def remove(string):
    for i in range(len(string)):

        # We can use string slicing to find the substring prior to the 
        # character to be removed AND the subtring after the character to
        # be removed.

        # since we will be using the position indicator several times, we can 
        # save that

        result = string[:i] + string[i+1:]

        print("Remove the position", i+1 ,":", removed)
        
remove("hello")
```

yields:

```
ello
hllo
helo
helo
hell
```

Other notes:

All Python functions return None if you don't provide an explicit return value, so we can remove that line.